# StreamWriter outputs ... at end of .txt file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, streamwriter

I am writing some text from a textbox to a .txt file, and after 40 characters, it just puts a '...'

Here is the code:

```
//defining the path as a string
string fileName1 = @"C:\Users\-----\AppData\Local\" + nameTextBox.Text + " FileName.txt";
        //checking if the file exists
        if (!File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            
            //if file does exist, open the file and edit it
            using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(fileName))
            {
                //using stream writer to write the file System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\-----\AppData\Local\" + NameTextbox.Text + "FileName.txt"); //open the file for writing.
                writer.Write(writingTextBox.Text); //write text box contents to the file. 
                writer.Close();
                writer.Dispose();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //if the file does not exist, create new file
            System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\-----\AppData\Local" + nameTextBox.Text + "FileName.txt");
            writer1.Write(writingTextBox); //write the textbox contents to the file.
            writer1.Close();
            writer1.Dispose();
        }
```

Please help,

Thankyou.

Comment: You have probably mistyped in `else` branch - `writer1.Write(writingTextBox);` should be `writer1.Write(writingTextBox.Text);`

Answer (score 0):

If you are just writing simple text data and you just want to overwrite this each time then you are better of using `WriteAllText`

```
string fileName = @"C:\Users\-----\AppData\Local\" + nameTextBox.Text + " FileName.txt";

File.WriteAllText(fileName, writingTextBox.Text));
```

No need to check if the file exists and have different processing.

If you wanted to Append to the file then you can also use `AppendAllText`.  But then you will have to first check if the file exists.